# Is it possible to auto-import files with webpack or React so that I don't need to `import` every time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, eslint

I very often need to write:

```js
<div style={{display:'flex'}}>
  ...
</div>
```

However, I'd ideally just write:

```js
<Row>
  ...
</Row>
```

But I don't want to need to `import Row from './Row'` every time.
What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

I'm happy to disable linting for specific variables.
Is there something I can do to webpack config to make it accessible to every React file?

Comment: Use a decent IDE that will auto-import for you. I recommend Webstorm

Comment: ^. There’s probably something out there that would let you full omit the `import`, but that would be considered bad practice – it’s good to be able to tell, statically and locally, where names in scope are coming from.

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for [https://stackoverflow.com/a/35164583/8426995](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35164583/8426995)

Comment: That's something not naturally supported by ECMAScript modules, and bundlers like webpack etc..., so for right module splitting (for example while using lazy load with chunks it's criticaly important), it's recommended to keep import statement.

As a **bad** but natural and working solution, you can put `Row` in `globalThis` object in this case `window`, `window.Row = yourcomponent`. it will be visible from anywhere without import

Answer (score 0):

check webpack [provide-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/), you would need to take your div to separate file & create identifier for that.